# 2010 Sharepoint Secure Form unsecured, List from Form needs to be secured

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to have security so that anyone can fill out a form, but only a small amount of people can see the underlying list? We are implementing an form that can contain sensitive information and as such only those who need to, should be able to view the list

Comment: Are you open to custom development? How are you creating the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can give users contribute permissions to the list, so they can add new items to the list and use the new form. Then you can modify the AllItems view and make it filter to something so that it doesn't show any item by default, for example make it filter on something that's always going to be false. Then give permissions to users who are supposed to see the underlying list data permissions to create their personal views so they can see the items in that list.